# SQL query: use UNION to find maximum and minimum values

Tags: sql, syntax-error, max, union, min

I'm trying to solve a task from an online SQL course. There are 2 tables: city and shipment linked by city_id primary key. City table has a long_name column and shipment has a weight column, which I need to have in the output. The task is to find cities with maximum and minimum weight of a single shipment.

I tried making 2 queries with order by and limit and then unify them, but it turns out that I can only order by and limit the resulting table, not both.

I searched for possible solutions, but they involve sub-queries, UNPIVOT, greatest() or least(), which haven't been introduced in the course yet. The task has to be solved with UNION if I understood correctly.

I appreciate any help with this.

Here the query I tried which results in ERROR: syntax error at or near "UNION" Position: 127

```
SELECT
    c.city_name, s.weight
FROM
    sql.city c
    JOIN sql.shipment s ON c.city_id = s.city_id
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 1

UNION

SELECT
    c.city_name, s.weight
FROM
    sql.city c
    JOIN sql.shipment s ON c.city_id = s.city_id
ORDER BY 2
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: You need a subqeury to use ORDER BY and LIMIT for a separate SELECT.

Comment: However, you're probably doing something odd here. A  [mcve] would make it easier to assist you!

Comment: Just use brackets `(select .. limit..) union all (select .. limit..)` to specify which query a LIMIT clause belongs to.